# Magento : Due to varnish wrong customer ID geting

Tags: magento, varnish

We using turpentine extension for  varnish with magento and my magento version is magento1.8

I am trying to get customer ID for GA script , When I logged In  and goto any category page  then I logout  and try to login with another customer . Issue is at this time it is display previous customer ID which is wrong

Note : When I cleared varnish cache then it's working fine

Guys can you please tell me how to fix  this issue

Thanks